# How to validate a specific form (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I realize my title may seem general but I have a specific problem I can't find the answer to. I made a form where people input information and I actively check their info to see if it is formatted correctly. If not an alert message pops up. So far I have three functions in my check. Calling example:

```
<input type="text" name="LastName" onblur="javascript:validateName(this.value);" required>
```

So I call each one individually in the html. Now what I would like to do is have a fourth function that turn the submit button on or off depending on the outcomes of the other functions. But, I do not know how to put in the parameters for the other functions because they currently use `this.value`. If it is unclear still I want

```
function validate submit(...) {
     if (validateName() == true && validatePhone() == true && validateEmail() == true){
          document.getElementById("btnformsubmission").disabled = false;                 
     }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I would say you would need a isValid flag which is set outside your individual validation functions and submit function, and if this flag is true, then you can allow submit inside your submit function.